# Dotted name doesn't work when I use usermod

Tags: command-line, users

I've been trying to register using `usermod` command my user that is `gonzalo.pincheira`.

My command is

```
usermod -aG docker $USER
```

But I get this error

```
usermod: user 'gonzalo.pincheira' does not exist
```

I don't understand why happen this. Using other users that doesn't have dot in the name, the command above works fine!

I use Ubuntu 14.04

Another weird things:

If I execute `whoami` I get `gonzalo.pincheira`.

If I execute this command to see all the users in the system, my user "gonzalo.pincheira" doesn't appears!!

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd

root
daemon
bin
sys
sync
games
man
lp
mail
news
uucp
proxy
www-data
backup
list
irc
gnats
nobody
libuuid
syslog
messagebus
usbmux
dnsmasq
avahi-autoipd
kernoops
rtkit
saned
whoopsie
speech-dispatcher
avahi
lightdm
colord
hplip
pulse
globant
sshd
sophosav
usermetrics
clickpkg
gpincheira
```

**Can anybody help me to understand this?**

Comment: Does it work as expected if you [quote your variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/22222)? `usermod -aG docker "$USER"`?

Comment: What does `echo $USER` output for your username?  Do you set your `$USER` variable anywhere, to make it say something different?

Comment: Is this a personal machine, or is it in some kind of corporate LDAP / Active Directory environment?

Comment: Information here may be useful to you https://askubuntu.com/questions/405638/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-having-a-dot-in-a-user-name

Comment: Is gpincheira a separate user account?

Comment: @steeldriver this is a LDAP / Active Directory environment

Comment: In which case it's likely that the `gonzalo.pincheira` user is defined in the LDAP database - what does `getent passwd | grep pincheira` say? Likely `usermod` is not able to make changes involving non-local users/groups (although it's possible another utility such as `gpasswd` can e.g. `gpasswd --add $USER docker`)