# How can use '@' in ubuntu username?

Tags: 16.04

can anybody tell me how to create a ubuntu user with having '@'. With help of bellow link I found how to add period in username but haven't found any clue for '@' yet.

[What are the disadvantages of having a dot in a user name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405638/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-having-a-dot-in-a-user-name#new-answer?newreg=920e3fbfd1dd422f83317e3e2769d9a9)

Comment: Do the same thing it says, but use `@` instead of `\.` in the regex.

Answer (score 2):

not sure why you would want to use such character in the user name, but here is one way (for username foo@t):

```
# useradd -m foo@t
# /bin/su - foo@t
$ id
uid=22284(foo@t) gid=22284(foo@t) groups=22284(foo@t)
```

then to set a password

```
# passwd foo@t
```

to delete such user (and all her/his files):

```
# userdel -r foo@t
```

Comment: That backslash is unnecessary - the shell will just translate that to `@`. Try `echo @ \@`

Comment: yes, you are indeed correct, not sure whether it's best to edit original answer or leave it to these comments ...