# Username change

Tags: username

I'm changing my username on Ubuntu 14.04 as read on another question and I then get this message.

> Please enter a username matching the regular expression configured
>   via the NAME_REGEX[_SYSTEM] configuration variable.  Use the `--force-badname'
>   option to relax this check or reconfigure NAME_REGEX.

I have no idea what this means or if it's anything serious. Is it serious?

Comment: What user name do you want?  Does it contain character that are not legal in user names?

Comment: The username I am trying to create is simply called ( Sub-Account ) because I didn't want to put any characters I thought it would see as illegal to the system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is an answer here by [CoalaWeb](https://askubuntu.com/users/70874/coalaweb) that may help you: https://askubuntu.com/a/232745/485705

> > "You normally get this message if you are trying to create a user with a name that contains characters that are considered to be un
> >     acceptable as per your NAME_REGEX file. You can try again changing the
> >     username with the GUI or you can relax the check by using the command
> >     line with the following command.
>
> `sudo adduser --force-badname <username>` and then if you want to add
>   the user to the sudo group run the following command.
>
> `sudo adduser <username> sudo`"

There is more information about why NOT to use characters considered unacceptable in a reply by [steveha](https://serverfault.com/users/19112/steveha) here: https://serverfault.com/a/73101

> "My advice to you is to follow the standard recommended by the default
>   NAME_REGEX. You can actually put nearly anything in a user name under
>   *NIX but you may encounter odd problems with library code that makes assumptions."

Comment: Okay cheers, it's that the PC is second hand and I wanted it to have my Username not theirs cheers for the help nonetheless

Comment: If it's not a character issue, you could try following the steps that this person (http://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username) has outlined in a terminal. First `ctrl`+`alt`+`T` to open the terminal and then `usermod` etc. to change your username.
If you're using unity, you can type "user accounts" in your dash and then edit your username directly in the GUI.

Comment: As the other post states you can't change the admin username while your logged in? I'm pretty sure the account I'm logged into is the admin for this computer (only account other than guest and the password was admin)